# Lighttpd 上で FastCGI の C言語のプログラムから `system()` で外部コマンドを実行したい

Tags: linux, c

Lighttpd と FastCGI をつかって、 C言語で書いたプログラムの中から、 `system()` で外部コマンドを実行というのは出来るのでしょうか。

`system("ls")` は実行出来たが、 `system("fswebcam・・・")` はダメです。

実行可能にするために、どこかに設定すべき項目があるのでしょうか。

---

**<<<追補です>>>**
アドバイスありがとうございます。
下記のようなプログラムでUSBカメラで撮影をしようとしています。
"TEST ABCDE"、"Request number xx"といった `printf`でのHTML出力は表示されるのでプログラム自体は実行されてるようです。
ただ、`system("fswebcam・・・")`で写真が撮れません。
./test.fcgiをキーインして実行させると、撮れます。
fcgiから動いてるcのプログラムから、さらに`system( )`で外部のコマンドを実行するときに、セキュリティ対策などで制限があるのか、あるとすれば解除する方法があるのかがわかりません。
実行権、オーナー、グループなど試したのですが解決できませんでした。

```
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int c, char** argv){
  int count = 0;
  while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0){
    printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
           "\r\n"
           "<html>\n"
           "<head>\n"
           "<title>FastCGI Test</title>\n"
           "</head>\n");
    printf("<body>\n");
    printf("<p>TEST ABCDE</p>\n");
    system("fswebcam -S 3 --line-colour \"#0000ff00\" /run/shm/fig/live.jpeg" );
    printf("<p>Request number %d</p>\n"
           "</body>\n"
           "</html>\n", ++count);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: まず、ダメと仰られている事がどうダメなのか説明された方が良いと思います。その際、期待している動作も添えると良いです。

Comment: さらに、再現手順・コードも添えると回答をもらいやすいと思います。[再現コードの書き方についてのヘルプ](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)が参考になります。(質問は後から[edit]できます)

Comment: `fswebcam` には `--log file:/path/to/file/outfile.log` のようにファイルにログを出せるオプションがあるようですが、ログの確認がまだならためしてみるといいかもしれません。 http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/fswebcam.1.html

Comment: 解決出来ました。ありがとうございます！！
fswebcam の --log　オプションを知りませんでした。
（fswebcam -?　で出てこなかった、-o と等価かな？）
ログに、下記の実行権関係のエラーがありました。
１：　Unable to find a source module that can read /dev/video0.
２：Error opening file for output: /run/shm/fig/live.jpeg
とりあえず、
Ａ：/dev/video0.は、オーナーとグループを Lighttpdと同じwww-data にする
Ｂ：/run/shm/fig/live.jpegは、実行権を777にする
これで、期待の動作になりました。
ただ、Ａの対処は正しくないような気が・・・
（corntab で自動撮影してるほうが動かなくなってしまった）
本質的解決法はどのようにするのが正解なのですか。

試行の途中で、そこらじゅうの実行権やオーナーなどを変えまくってしまったので、インストールのやり直しから再度やってみます、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決されてよかったです。自己解決された場合は、自分で回答を書いて後で解決済みにしておくと、質問のステータスが分かりやすくなると同時に、他の方の参考になります。

Comment: 「ステータスを解決済みにする方法」が分からないのですが、見るべきページなどを教えてください。
お手数をおかけします。

Comment: 1. 自分で回答を投稿します 2. 回答の左側、投票ボタンの下にチェックマークがあるので、クリックします (ただし回答を投稿してから2日待つ必要があります)。これで解決済みにできます。ヘルプページとしては[こちら](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)が該当すると思います。

Comment: それからちなみにですが、コメントスレッド内の人に通知を飛ばすには @ento などと書く必要があります。その方が返事をもらいやすいです。(今回は過去の質問を見返していて、ちょうど気付くことができました。)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。
USBカメラの実行権の問題でした。
実行権を777に設定して、lighttpdのユーザIDからも実行可能にしたところFCGIを通しての撮影が出来ました。